# Visual Studio 2022 can't create exe with all dll's

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have project in .NET 4.8 and i want to publish as one exe file (with all dll) and app.config. When i use VS 2017 i just choose publish and to file. But now i have Publish wizard which create installer (which install i don't know where). When I go to project properties this same wizard.

Edit: this issue absent for .net 6 app

Publish Wizard which I get:

[image: Publish Wizard]

P.S. I hope my english wasn't too terrible

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Publish a single-file app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?source=recommendations&tabs=vs#publish-a-single-file-app).

Comment: this is what I expect to do but when i click publish i got a publish wizard(this on the picture what i posted)

Comment: Hi Toru DxD, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I forgot as I had to wait two days to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing in a single-file app isn't supported by .NET Framework 4.8. This is for .NET core and higher version of launguage.